# Sync several users with their own Google Calendar using API v3

Tags: php, calendar, google-api, google-calendar-api

My company have a web app with its own calendar and we used **Google Calendar API v1** (Zend_GData) for sync the data. Each user had both calendars synchronized without problems. We want start to use Google Calendar API v3.

The problem is the next one, how could sync all the users with their own google calendar using **Google Calendar API v3**? All the examples I've read require each user registers in Google Cloud Console .

I would like some guide for my problem, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just your application will have to register in Google Cloud Console, your users will have to login with their Google accounts and allow your app to use the calendar resources.

Here's a reference https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer

Another option is to use the private XML or iCAL feed that each calendar has. You can find it on the calendar configurations.