# How to synchronize google calendar with acc in web app

Tags: java, web-applications, google-calendar-api

I am creating a web booking system in Java with Spring and Hibernate frameworks. My task is to synchronize admin google calendar, so all reservations created in my web app will display on his calendar.
Admin can choose if he wants to synchronize or not.
My problem is how to synchronize the calendar with an account, how to add events, and how to drop synchronize if admin chooses NO SYNCHRONIZATION.
(System may have more than one user).
Can someone help me, please?
Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

Based from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19706849/sync-several-users-with-their-own-google-calendar-using-api-v3), your application will have to register in Google Cloud Console and your users will have to login with their Google accounts and allow your app to use the calendar resources.

> Here's a reference https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer
>
> Another option is to use the private XML or iCAL feed that each calendar has. You can find it on the calendar configurations.

You may also check this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/sync) which describes how to implement "incremental synchronization" of calendar data. Using this method, you can keep data for all calendar collections in sync while saving bandwidth.